# jQuery removeClass() callback function

Tags: jquery

is it possible to have a callback function for the removeClass() function in jQuery? I have the  following code:

```
var pane = $(this).attr("rel");
var current = $('.active-pane');

current.fadeOut("slow").removeClass('active-pane');            
$("#pane-"+pane).addClass('active-pane');
```

So basically I want current to fade out, then have the active-pane class removed, then once thats happened add the active-pane class to the new element. At the moment these events happen at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.fadeout` method has a callback.

```
current.fadeOut("slow", function() {
  current.removeClass('active-pane');            
  $("#pane-"+pane).addClass('active-pane');
});
```